# rails support for xmlparse(DOCUMENT, xml string)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm not able to insert data to a field of type xml.

looks like I Need to call XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT...) instead of just passing the string through.

e.g.
XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT 'Manual...')

Anybody know how to get this working in Rails?

Here's the error message I get when i attempt the insert.

PGError: ERROR:  invalid XML content
LINE 1: ...2010, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 'new', xml '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to use `XMLPARSE`.  From the error message, it rather looks like you might have quoting problem in the surrounding code, because that looks like the `INSERT` statement itself being passed in as XML value.

Comment: postgres will interpret a simple string as xml content. (Nokogiri::XML(UriHelper.fetch_uri(uri)).css("PubmedArticle").to_xml seems to work fine, but i'd rather avoid the parse step). If you want to store an xml document, i think you have to do an explicit parse or switch modes with SET XML OPTION DOCUMENT.  Maybe there's some way to inject some sql in the AR transaction that I don't know about?

Comment: The default is XML OPTION CONTENT, which should accept anything that DOCUMENT accepts.  Maybe you should turn on statement logging in the server to see what statement it receives.  I think there is something butchered.

Comment: with XML OPTION CONTENT my document is rejected (unless i dump the DTD header and xml line with that nokogiri extraction).

Comment: I never found anything better than  Nokogiri::XML(UriHelper.fetch_uri(uri)).css("PubmedArticle").to_xml